# How to carry on executing Future sequence despite failure?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

The `traverse` method from `Future` object stops at first failure. I want a tolerant/forgiving version of this method which on occurrence of errors carries on with the rest of the sequence.

Currently we have added the following method to our utils:

```
def traverseFilteringErrors[A, B <: AnyRef]
                           (seq: Seq[A])
                           (f: A => Future[B]): Future[Seq[B]] = {
  val sentinelValue = null.asInstanceOf[B]
  val allResults = Future.traverse(seq) { x =>
    f(x) recover { case _ => sentinelValue }
  }
  val successfulResults = allResults map { result =>
    result.filterNot(_ == sentinelValue)
  }
  successfulResults
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A genuinely useful thing (generally speaking) would be to be able to promote the error of a future into a proper value. Or in other words, transform a `Future[T]` into a `Future[Try[T]]` (the succesful return value becomes a `Success[T]` while the failure case becomes a `Failure[T]`). Here is how we might implement it:

```
// Can also be done more concisely (but less efficiently) as:
// f.map(Success(_)).recover{ case t: Throwable => Failure( t ) }
// NOTE: you might also want to move this into an enrichment class
def mapValue[T]( f: Future[T] ): Future[Try[T]] = {
  val prom = Promise[Try[T]]()
  f onComplete prom.success
  prom.future
}
```

Now, if you do the following:

```
Future.traverse(seq)( f andThen mapValue )
```

You'll obtain a succesful `Future[Seq[Try[A]]]`, whose eventual value contains a `Success` instance for each successful future, and a `Failure` instance for each failed future.
If needed, you can then use `collect` on this seq to drop the `Failure` instances and keep only the sucessful values.

In other words, you can rewrite your helper method as follows:

```
def traverseFilteringErrors[A, B](seq: Seq[A])(f: A => Future[B]): Future[Seq[B]] = {
  Future.traverse( seq )( f andThen mapValue ) map ( _ collect{ case Success( x ) => x } )
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Could you comment on why the alternative (`f.map(Success...`) is less efficient?

Comment: Because `map` as well as `recover` create instances of `Promise` and return their associated `Future`. That's two `Promise` instanciations instead of just one for my alternative solution. Also, the "concise" version unwraps the `Try` instance (that is stored inside the `Promise`  instances) only to rewrap it immeditely as a `Success` or `Failure` instance, which is kind of wasteful. Of course, you'd need to profile to see if it actually makes such any kind of meaningful difference.

Comment: The "andThen" combinator is actually side effecting hence you'll end up with the same type as the original future when you apply it. The example above should actually be something like  `Future.traverse(m) { mapValue } map ( _ collect{ case Success( x ) => x } )`

Comment: You are mistaken. This is `Function1.andThen`, not `Future.andThen`

Comment: not clear how mapValue transforms Future[T] to Future[Try[T]]. Also what is  the line f onComplete prom.success . Is not prom.succes suppose to have an argument of Type Try[T]?