# Given a Future[T] can I write function with onComplete callback which returns T?

Tags: scala

I have this method:

```
def findById(id: String): Customer = {
     (new CustomerDaoEs).retrieve(Id[Customer](id)) onComplete {
      case Success(customer) => customer
      case Failure(t) => {
        throw new InvalidIdException(id.toString, "customer")
      }
    }
  }
```

Of course, the issue is that this returns Unit instead of Customer... So basically onComplete does not really behave like pattern matching.

Is there any way to keep returning Customer (or Option[Customer]) and make this work nice (I mean to keep this onComplete clean structure)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that onComplete is non-blocking. So instead you would have to use Await and return the result.

```
def findById(id: String): Customer = 
  Await.result(
    awaitable = (new CustomerDaoEs).retrieve(Id[Customer](id))),
    atMost = 10.seconds
  )
```

However I would rather suggest to keep the code non-blocking and make findById return `Future[Customer]`.

Comment: But what if the `id` is wrong. How about returning `Future[Either[String,Customer]]` if you want a message or `Future[Option[Customer]]`

Comment: I do not think that every exception should be mapped to InvalidIdException like in the given answer. What if the connection has been closed for whatever reason? That is certainly not an invalid id.

Comment: @ziggystar: the futures already encapsulate the error (if any) so using either is generally redundant. For the cases where you really need to make the exception explicit, using `Try` is now more idiomatic. See my other answer here for some related helper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15776974/1632462. But in any case, this is helpful when mapping/flatMapping over the future, APIs should not return a `Future[Either[String,Customer]]` (nor `Future[Try[Customer]]`). As I said, it's redundant.

Answer (score 5):

You could change `exception` using `recover` method:

```
def findById(id: String): Future[Customer] = {
  (new CustomerDaoEs).retrieve(Id[Customer](id)).recover{ case _ => throw new InvalidIdException(id.toString, "customer") }
}
```

Then you could use your method like this:

```
val customer = Await.result(findById("cust_id"), 5.seconds)
```

Alternatively you could replace exception with `None`:

```
def findById(id: String): Future[Option[Customer]] = {
  (new CustomerDaoEs).
    retrieve(Id[Customer](id)).
    map{ Some(_) }.
    recover{ case _ => None }
}
```