# Can't get flatten of Try into a for comprehension

Tags: list, scala, try-catch, future, for-comprehension

This is a combination of a stylistic question, and my attempts to broaden my Scala understanding.

I've got a list containing Future's, I want to compute the values of the futures, transform into Option's, and flatten the list using a for comprehension:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val l= List(Future.successful(1),Future.failed(new IllegalArgumentException))

implicit def try2Traversible[A](xo: Try[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toOption.toList

val res = for{f <- l; v <- f.value} yield v

scala> res: List[scala.util.Try[Int]] = List(Success(1), Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException))

res.flatten
res16: List[Int] = List(1)
```

What I want to do is get the flatten stage into the for comprehension, anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this is incorrect:

```
for{f <- l; v <- f.value} yield v
```

It appears to work in your case only because the futures are already fulfiled, which is why their `value` member is defined.
However in the general case they might not yet be fulfilled when you execute the for comprehension, and thus `value` will return `None` 
(despite the fact that at some point they will eventually be fulfilled).
By example, try this in the REPL:

```
val f1 = Future{ 
  Thread.sleep(3000) // Just a test to illustrate, never do this!
  1
}
val f2 = Future{ 
  Thread.sleep(3000) // Just a test to illustrate, never do this!
  throw new IllegalArgumentException
}

val l = List( f1, f2 )
for{f <- l; v <- f.value} yield v
```

The result is an empty list, because none of the futures in `l` is fulfilled yet. Then wait a bit (at most 3 seconds) and reexecute the for comprehension (the last line), and you will get a non empty list because the futures have finally been fulfilled.

To fix this, you will have to either block (that is, wait for all the futures to be fulfiled) using `scala.concurrent.Await`, or stay in the asynchronous world by using something like `Future.map` or `Future.flatMap`.
By example, if you want to block, you could do:

```
Await.result( Future.sequence( l ), duration.Duration.Inf )
```

`Await.result` waits for the result of the future, allowing to go from the asynchronous world to the synchronous world. The result of the above is a `List[Int]`
The problem now is that you lose the failure cases (the result is not `List[Try[Int]]` as you wanted), and will actually rethrow the first exception.
To fix this, you can use this helper method that I posted in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776974/1632462
Using it, you can do:

```
Await.result( Future.sequence( l map mapValue ), duration.Duration.Inf )
```

This will wait until all the futures are fulfiled (either with a correct value, or with an error) and return the expected `List[Try[Int]]`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to traverse to `Try` object as if it were an `Option` (i.e. a 0 or 1 element collection) within the for-comprehension itself.
For this traversal to work there has to be a conversion from the `Try` type to the `Option` type.

This should work:

```
implicit def try2option[A](xo: Try[A]) = xo.toOption

val res = for (f <- l; t <- f.value; x <- t) yield x
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a `Future` around your final result to retain the asynchronous nature of the computation.

The nice way to do this (and obtain a `Future[List[Int]]`) would be (probably what you tried):

```
for {
  f <- l    // Extract individual future
  v <- f    // Extract value from future
} yield v
```

Unfortunately this translates to:

```
l.flatMap(f => f.map(v => v))
```

Which does not work, because `Future` does not inherit `GenTraversableOnce` (and probably shouldn't), but `List` needs this trait for its `flatMap`.

<del>However, we can do this manually:

    val res = l.foldRight(Future.successful(List.empty[Int])) {  
      case (x,xs) => xs.flatMap(vxs => x.map(vx => vx :: vxs))
    }</del>

We can use `Future.sequence` to do that:

```
Future.sequence(l)
```

This will return a `Future[List[Int]]` which only completes when all futures are completed and will contain all values of the futures that completed successfully.

Comment: `Future.sequence` should be used to transform a list of futures into a future list.

Comment: Hahaha, I see. Reinvented the wheel. Updated.