# Transform Future[T] to Future[Try[T]]

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to understand following answer  [How to carry on executing Future sequence despite failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775824/how-to-carry-on-executing-future-sequence-despite-failure).
(Hope thats not a down vote worthy as i am trying to understand the code here.)

I dont understand how mapValue is transforming Future[T] to Future[Try[T]]

```
def mapValue[T]( f: Future[T] ): Future[Try[T]] = {
  val prom = Promise[Try[T]]()
  f onComplete prom.success
  prom.future
}
```

the line f onComplete prom.success, what is it doing. My understanding was prom.success has to take an object of type Try[T] but here it does not do that. Also there is no assignment to f which transforms Future[T] to Future[Try[T]]. 
Moreover, anThen on Future is supposed to be a sideffect and is supposed to return the same future value that came into it, so not sure how does the transformation happen.

Comment: Why wrapping `Try` there, as `Future` handle errors

Comment: look at the original question link to understand the context

Comment: Can you please give an example? Namely - `mapValue ( example ) ` and then expected output?

Comment: @KevinMeredith look at the link posted in the question. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775824/how-to-carry-on-executing-future-sequence-despite-failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f onComplete prom.success` line is parsed by Scala compiler as following:

1. Dots and parentheses can be ommited in some cases, so `f onComplete x` is a way to write `f.onComplete(x)`.
2. Compiler sees that `onComplete` method takes as argument function `f: Try[T] => U`. You also passed a function as an argument, `Promise#success`, which has a compatible signature.

So what the method is doing is creating a new `Promise` (writeable future) of type `Try[T]`, and completing that promise with wrapped `Try[T]` as original future completes. Then it's returns new `Future[Try[T]]` obtained from promise.

Comment: thanks @maxim what is confusing is, how is the promise getting completed here, prom.success like you pointed returns a function.  and how does the promise.future has T assigned to it? are you suggesting that when f.onComplet is executed, the value of f is passed to prom.success ? a

Comment: When you invoke `prom.success`, a future that promise returned is completed by promise internal logic. There is no variable assignment in your code, it's inside promise code.

Comment: usually Promise#Success takes a parameter which is returned inside Future. here prom.succes is not taking any param.

Comment: It takes, but here you do not invoke it. Referencing `Promise#success` without a parameter you reference a function itself, and this function is passed to `onComplete`. So `onComplete` will invoke `success` with value that original future will have.

Comment: ah! one last question, thanks for your patience. how is original value of the future, T in this case becomes Try[T], when it passed to Promise#Success.

Comment: It's `onComplete` logic, `onComplete` will trigger despite of failures, so it will need to wrap `T` into `Try[T]` to distinguish success from failure. `Promise#success` will receive this `Try[T]` as-is and pass it into new future. Wrapping into `Try[T]` is internal logic of `Future#onComplete`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Maxim's answer, `f onComplete prom.success` can be re-written as:

```
f.onComplete(prom.success)
```

or

```
f.onComplete(prom.success(_))
```

or

```
f.onComplete { resultOfFutureAsTry =>
  prom.success(resultOfFutureAsTry)
}
```

`prom.success` sets the *success* value of the promise. Thus, no matter what happens inside the original future `f`, (an exception is thrown, or the future completes successfully), the new future (returned by `prom.future`, and created after the original future is completed) is always a successful future. Sometimes that successful future contains a `Failure[T]`, and sometimes a `Success[T]`.

Side note: Often, `f.onComplete` is used more like this:

```
f.onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(s"Yay, $x worked!")
  case Failure(ex) => println(s"Darn, it failed: $ex")
}
```

But this is just a convenient way to write a function `f: Try[T] => U`.